# Windows 10 SSH client: password-less access from ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh

I have two machines. first is `ubuntu` and second is a `windows` client.
I want to connect to windows form my ubuntu.
I create a ssh-key from my windows without password. I copy windows public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Now when I use this command from ubuntu:

```
ssh ***-pc@192.168.8.***
```

It shows password promot.

Comment: Uh, have you copied the keypair to your ubuntu `~/.ssh`? What does ssh -vvv says?

Comment: "a windows client" -- Somewhat misleading. In terms of SSH the computer that connects (uses `ssh`) is a client. If you want to connect to Windows then windows is a server. Please [edit] and clarify "I create a ssh-key from my windows without password". Do you mean "without passphrase"? A key pair should be created on the client (if not already there) and the public key placed in `authorized_keys` on the server. Please verify if you did this correctly (and not the other way around).